# How to click on a button by the link text using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, linktext

I know, there are plenty of tutorials out there for this task. But it seems like I'm doing something wrong, I need help by telling me how to press it, doesn't need to be by text.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, 'login or register'))
    )
    element.click()
except:
    print('exception occured')
    driver.quit()
```

I'm trying to press the "login or register" button from the site wilds.io, but it seems like it can't find that button after 10 seconds. I'm probably accessing the button in a wrong way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To click on the element with text as **login or register** you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "login or register"))).click()
  ```
- Using `PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "login or register"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH` using `text()`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[text()='login or register']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH` using `contains()`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(., 'login or register')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: It seems like using XPATH with text() is the only one that's working for me. I'll use it since its a solution for clicking the button.

Comment: Also, how did you get the XPATH? When I try to get it, I have 
`/html/body/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[5]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/span`
and not
`//*[text()='login or register']`

Comment: @JohnFrames These are generic techniques to convert _linkText_ / _partialLinkText_ into _xpath_.